# How to define a vector function

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to define a vector function in `x` like this `[sin(x),sin(2*x), ... ,sin(100*x)]` where `x` is a variable. What I defined is that :

```
for i=1:100
H(i)=@(x) sin(i*x);
end
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232323/combining-anonymous-functions-in-matlab

Comment: What about `H = @(x) sin((1:100).*x)`?

Comment: @MendiBarel Could you please tell me about this function  [sin(x),....,sin(10x),cos(x),....,cos(10x)]?

Comment: It's basically the same, `H = @(x) [sin((1:10).*x), cos((1:10).*x)] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1, use vectorization (simplest, fastest):

```
H=@(N,x) sin((1:N)'.*x);
%With the '.*' operation u can create the full matrix in single call:
N=100; 
x=0:0.01:pi;
M=H(N, x)
```

Method 2, use arrayfun (can generalized to other functions):

```
N=10;
H=@(x) arrayfun(@(i)sin(i*x),1:N);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even combine multiple functions in a function handle, e.g.

```
H = @(x) sin((1:length(x))'.*x);
```

This always returns a square matrix; in your case a 315x315 matrix. The first 100 rows are identical to the solution suggested by Mendi Barel